# Conditional formatting with formula not working but working with text

Tags: excel

I want to create a calendar and fill some cell with a color depending of the day of the week.
So I have something like this:
[image: Day of the week]

The number are the day of the month, and the row below is automaticly filled by a formula, with a custom cell format to determinate the day of the week (Samedi = Saturday / Dimanche = Sunday):

```
=DATE($B$16;$B$15;B1)
```

Where:
B16 = the year
B15 = the month

Here is the custom cell format:

[image: custom format]

So I want a column to be colored if the day of the week is "samedi" or "dimanche"

I tried to use this formating rule

[image: formating rule]

But it works only if in the G2 cell the text "samedi" is explicitly written. It doesn't work if the value "samedi" comes from the formula.

Is there a way to apply conditional formatting based on the value displayed in the cell provided by the formula?

Comment: Use `WEEKDAY()` function --> `=WEEKDAY(B2,2)>5`

Comment: Cell Formatting is `Façade` the cells are reading as number and not text. [Read_Here](https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/formatting-as-facade/)

Comment: Just a remark for the non-French speaking people: `jjjj` stands for `jour`, which means `day`, not `year` (or `jaar` in Dutch).